# Hiding a button onClick="" before launching the following method calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am not very familiar with inline JS. I have a button such as

```
<button onClick="return doSomething()"></button>
```

How do I hide & disable the button before return and doSomething are called? (jQuery available too).

I need the button to be hidden & disabled before the onClick methods are called.

Comment: You want the button hidden, disabled, or both?

Comment: Why not just hide/disable it as the first line of `doSomething()`?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Somehow the function is still called if I click it fast twice. Can something be done to this. I tried onMouseDown event too.

Comment: I edited my answer according to the update. And no - javascript is faster than you.

Comment: Okay, there was some caching going on on local env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
<button onClick="this.disabled = true;this.style.display = 'none';return doSomething()"></button>
```

Or just do it in your doSomething function:

```
<button onClick="return doSomething(this)"></button>

function doSomething(obj){
    obj.disabled = true;
    obj.style.display = 'none'
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onClick="this.style.display = 'none';this.disabled = true;return doSomething()">Button</button>
```